# Problems getting the page source with urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen

The webplayer on this site http://rockantenne.de/webplayer has a playlist available with all the songs played so far on that day.

When I am in *Firefox* and press Ctrl-U to see the source code of the page I can see all the songs played. However if I use **urllib2.urlopen** and then read() it, everything is the same except the songs are left out.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page uses AJAX to load the songlist asynchronously, from http://www.rockantenne.de/webplayer/xml/livesongcache.xml?82321.

Load that URL instead, and parse the returned XML yourself.

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much. May I asked where you found the information?

Comment: @derwahre_tj: I used the developer tools of my browser. Chrome, Safari and Firefox all can tell you what requests were made by a page.

Comment: unfortunately not completely. because by having a closer look I saw that you can just get the most recent played songs each time you call the link, not the complete list like you get it when you do the ctrl-u in firefox.

Comment: @derwahre_tj: You'll have to analyse how that page processes the URL and data; that's way too localized to answer here on SO.